# Is there Stack Exchange Site for people management or team management

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Hopefully there should be one , if no  if any body can provide another link please.

Comment: Will this include Project Management?

Comment: Will this include herding cats? (managing programmers)

Comment: @Kit,@Peter Ajtai  Yes for both of your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encourage any of these

[**Project Management**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management)

[**IT Management**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7502/it-management)

[**Systems Engineering and Project Management**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6537/systems-engineering-and-project-management)

[**Leadership**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17814/leadership)

[**Consultant/Client/Team Relations**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1959/consultant-client-team-relations)

Answer (score -1):

Not to shuffle you around, but http://meta.stackexchange.com would be a great place to ask this as well.

note: this is apparently wrong, and meta.stackexchange.com is for SE 1.0 sites, at least for now.  And meta.stackoverflow *is* the place where the question should be asked, as was done here.

Comment: This site is for SE 1.0 sites.  With the new SE 2.0 sites and Area 51, the site you linked to is not appropriate.

Comment: @Rchern Yes, but he asked about starting an SE 2.0 site about people or team management. Please double check his question.

Comment: Right, SE 2.0 has nothing to do with meta.stackexchange.com.  SE 1.0 sites will eventually be phased out iirc.

Comment: @Rchern Ok, two issues:  He was asking about a new area51 community.  Those _are_ discussed at meta.stackexchange.com.  So he should go there, right?  Second, SE2.0 is the interface used by cooking.stackexchange and other beta sites...  Aren't those the kinds used by area 51?  The only thing SE 1.0 applies to is SO/SU/SF, and this here MSO.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: No.  Area51 *is* SE2.0.  SE1.0 is something separate and does not refer to SOFU.

Comment: @Rchern.  Okay, then I have no idea what SE 1.0 refers to, maybe it was just the first version UI for the area51 sites.  But isn't my answer still correct, since area51 sites are discussed at meta.stackexchange?

Comment: SE 1.0 sites were the previous model. People were licensing the framework, and making their sites based on it. Questions about it were to direct to meta.stackexchange.com, then. [The Stack Exchange system has been changed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/), with the 2.0, and the introduction of the whole Area51 process. The new sites are linked to the original trilogy, and questions should be on meta.stackoverflow.com (for now), while meta.stackexchange.com is for the remaining SE 1.0 sites.

Comment: @Gnoupi.  Ok, so SE 1.0 was sites like mathoverflow.com?  Have you been to meta.stackexchange lately?  It appears to be filled with questions about new sites, which I assumed were related to area51.  This is confusing.  So I should change my answer and he should _not_ got to meta.stackexchange to discuss a new area51 site?